# How to do a Wget with powershell and output to a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to do a WGET and have the output go to a text file.

so far all attempts have failed.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin> For ($i=1; $i -lt 5; $i++) 
 {wget.exe  www.zillabunny.com | out-file C:\temp\wget.txt}
```

leaves an empty text file

and

```
For ($i=1; $i -lt 5; $i++)  {wget.exe  www.zillabunny.com} > C:\temp\wget.txt
```

gives me

> : The term '>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:60
>   + For ($i=1; $i -lt 5; $i++)  {wget.exe  www.zillabunny.com} > wget.txt
>   +                                                            ~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (>:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to enclose the `for` loop in a scriptblock and output all at once. For example:

```
& {
  for ( $i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++ ) {
    wget.exe -O - www.zillabunny.com
  }
} | out-file sample.txt
```

This will run the command `wget.exe www.zillabunny.com` 5 times and write the output to sample.txt.

If you just want to say "do something *x* times," you can also write it like this and dispense with the extra scriptblock:

```
1..5 | foreach-object {
  wget.exe -O - www.zillabunny.com
} | out-file sample.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This also explains why sometimes when I was testing things I was getting a text file that said "wget.exe www.zillabunny.com" 4 times

Comment: hm I think I actually spoke too soon, the first code block just creates an empty txt file.

Comment: the second code block also just creates a blank text file?

Comment: That depends on what `wget.exe www.zillabunny.com` outputs. Start by replacing `wget.exe www.zillabunny.com` with just `"Hello, world"` (quoted string) and you will see the effect more clearly.

Comment: Also using these codeblocks i'm noticing i'm getting the output on the screen.

Comment: Ok "hello world" seems to output directly to the sample.txt

Comment: wget looks like this

PS C:\temp> wget.exe www.zillabunny.com
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
--2014-07-08 11:37:01--  http://www.zillabunny.com/
Resolving www.zillabunny.com... 74.208.120.202
Connecting to www.zillabunny.com|74.208.120.202|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 308 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.26'

100%[==============================================================================>] 308         --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-07-08 11:37:01 (4.83 MB/s) - `index.html.26' saved [308/308]

Comment: Does `wget.exe www.zillabunny.com | out-file output.txt` work? Why run it multiple times?

Comment: The [wget documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) tells how to write to standard output instead of a file: `wget -O - http://www.zillabunny.com`. (`Out-File` in PowerShell won't work if wget doesn't write to standard output.)

Comment: & {
  for ( $i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++ ) 
  {
   wget.exe -O - www.zillabunny.com
  }
} | Out-File C:\temp\sample.txt

works perfect!! thanks!

Comment: Very good. I updated the code in my answer. Feel free to accept.